# Syntax error on this mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm getting an error on my MYSQL trigger. I've used some form of syntax but the syntax error still appear. Hopefully somebody could help me.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_table_a AFTER INSERT ON table_a
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE colorL VARCHAR(7);
  SET linesT = (
    SELECT COUNT(id)       
      FROM lineas 
      WHERE fk_id = NEW.fk_id
  );
  IF (linesT = 0) THEN
    SET colorL = '#D3D3D3';         
  ELSE IF (linesT = 1) THEN
    SET colorL = ( 
      SELECT l.color 
        FROM sel_lineas AS tl  
          INNER JOIN lineas  AS l ON l.id = tl.line_id 
        WHERE tl.fk_id = NEW.fk_id 
    );          
  ELSE
    SET colorL = '#000000';
  END IF;
  UPDATE tabla_colors  SET colour_l = colorL WHERE id = NEW.fk_id;
END;
```

I'd appriciate any help you can provide.

Here is the error message:
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE colorL VARCHAR(7); SET linesT = ( SELECT COUNT' at line 1

Comment: you could also add the actual error message. it may be helpful

Comment: Syntax looks good, perhaps you are missing the delimiter.

Comment: At the end works without the DECLARE statement, I complete the trigger only using SET. Thnks